# Not able to regenerate file using add_custom_command when it has modified source file

Tags: cmake

I am generating `.cc` and `.h` file using protoc tool, but when I am modifying the file then CMake is not taking new changes. Can someone tell me how can u generate new `.cc` and `.h` file when `.proto` file get changes?

Below is my cmake command:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT SensorMessage.pb.h SensorMessage.pb.cc 
              COMMAND protoc
              -I ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/telemetry/common
              --cpp_out=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
              ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/SensorMessage.proto)
```

Comment: You need to tell CMake about *dependencies* of the command. Do that with *DEPENDS* option.

Answer (score 0):

Simply adds DEPENDS to the add_custom_command:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT SensorMessage.pb.h SensorMessage.pb.cc 
    COMMAND protoc -I ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/telemetry/common 
            --cpp_out=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
            ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/SensorMessage.proto
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/SensorMessage.proto
)
```